# Print label on circle markers in leaflet in Rshiny

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

Great R Gurus,

Is there any possible way to embed label on top of the circle markers in Rshiny to get something like following:

[image]

Here is a quick example for the reference:

```
# Some fake data
df <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(
  cbind(
    (runif(20) - .5) * 10 - 90.620130,  # lng
    (runif(20) - .5) * 3.8 + 25.638077  # lat
  ),
  data.frame(type = factor(
    ifelse(runif(20) > 0.75, "p", "s"),
    c("s", "p")
  ))
)

# leaflet map
leaflet(df) %>% addTiles() %>% addCircleMarkers(label = ~type)
```

I would like to print labels (i.e. 's' and 'p') on the top of the marker.
Your time to answer is highly appreciated...

Comment: have a look [here](http://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-labels). labelOptions is what you want to adjust by setting `noHide = TRUE` and adjusting the `offset`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a `labelOptions` argument to your `addCircleMarkers` function call. By default, the labels appear as popups when you hover.

Using your the rest of your code:

```
leaflet(df) %>% addTiles() %>% addCircleMarkers(stroke = FALSE, label = ~type,
    labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE, offset=c(0,-12), textOnly = TRUE))
```

`noHide = TRUE` is the key

`textOnly = TRUE` removes popup bubble

Comment: Having posted my answer, I've just noticed that TimSalabim gave the solution above!

Comment: Perfect. Very handy... Thanks Jeremy!